# Can a person start new businesses to compete relentlessly with someone they hate?

Tags: harassment, competition

Let's take two people, Alice and Bob. Alice offends Bob in some way and Bob is determined to take revenge. He does this by starting new businesses to compete with Alice, e.g. if Alice owns a restaurant, he starts a new restaurant nearby, sells similar food, and sells it more cheaply (because he's willing to take a loss to get revenge, and he has the resources to sustain the loss). If Alice moves locations, he moves too. If Alice switches businesses, he switches too.

Is it legal for Bob to do this kind of thing? If it violates a law, which one would it be?

This kind of behavior sounds obnoxious enough that I'm guessing it is illegal, but I can't find a law that prohibits it. It doesn't seem like harassment, since Bob isn't humiliating or embarrassing Alice. It doesn't seem like unfair competition, because presumably once Bob achieves his aim of driving Alice out of business, he won't raise prices to unreasonable levels, in fact he'd probably shut up shop too. I'm tagging the question with "harassment" and "competition" anyway, since I can't think of anything else.

If the jurisdiction matters, assume the EU. If the country matters, assume Germany.

Comment: Did you watch the last season of "Curb Your Enthusiasm"? A "revenge business" was a running plotline.

Comment: Just wondering: why do you think this would _not_ be legal?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110581/discussion-on-question-by-allure-can-a-person-start-new-businesses-to-compete-re).

Comment: Something like a software company [giving away their program for free](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_wars#First_Browser_War_(1995%E2%80%932001)) to crush its competitors? The court [condemned](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/United_States_v._Microsoft_Corp.) them.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni That wasn't done as any sort of revenge, though. The basis for the suit was anti-competitive practices... but, honestly, the suit (and ruling) was utter nonsense. If it were actual anti-competitive behavior just to drive a competitor out of business, they'd have started charging for IE once Netscape was gone. Obviously, they never did and nowadays essentially all browsers are free downloads and the thought of _not_ packaging a browser with a desktop operating system is almost unthinkable.

Comment: Interestingly, in the US, collaborating with competitors to set pricing is illegal (anti-trust). If Bob is funding it with other people's money, setting prices in a way that nets you negative revenue without a reasonable business plan to make money will drive away capital investors . It is "illegal" to lie or mislead investors. If Bob were completely self funded, this is perfectly legal, although it's a bit self-destructive. Alice can easily sell shop and relocate easier than Bob (running a negative revenue) could. So Bob needs a much much larger pool of capital to enact his plan for revenge.

Comment: One of the questions to ask oneself is, in what way would Bob's actions be notably different from a genuine competitor trying to get all Alice's business at that place. If there are differences, those might be the actual starting point, else it sounds just like normal competition.

Comment: Sounds like what [Ray did to Richard and Maurice](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/McDonald%27s#History).

Comment: @Gnudiff the difference is Bob follows Alice around until Alice gives up. If Alice moves locations, he moves too. If Alice switches businesses, he switches too.

Comment: @Allure if that is the only difference, it sounds tricky, as neither action seems illegal by itself. And he is not threatening Alice personally. Not sure if businesses can be "harassed", but perhaps if there is a history of personal harassment and/or restraining orders, it might be possible to somehow let them apply to his presence in his business as well.

Comment: @Shorlan It's not "easy" to relocate a legitimate business, even in the best of circumstances. Alice has a business, but Bob has a farce; he can probably relocate more cheaply.

Comment: "It doesn't seem like unfair competition..."  It's not fair simply because the customers don't notice a difference. Laws protect business owners as well as non-business owners; and, it's debatable whether a monopoly is "okay" simply because it's prices are low.

Answer (score 49, accepted):

Generally speaking, there's nothing wrong with setting up shop to compete with someone, even if you hate them, and even if you hope to bring them to financial ruin.

But there are laws surrounding what is and is not fair competition, and the behavior you're describing -- relying on greater resources to cut prices until a competitor folds up shop -- is known as "predatory pricing." In the United States, it's illegal under the Clayton Act, [15 U.S.C. § 2](https://www.law.cornell.edu/uscode/text/15/2), assuming that Bob is cutting prices below cost, and that Alice's exit from the market could lead to a monopoly for Bob.

I don't know the limits on predatory pricing anywhere else, but my understanding is that it's illegal throughout the E.U., including in Germany, where [Wal-Mart has struggled mightily to adapt to local competition law](https://medium.com/better-marketing/why-walmart-failed-in-germany-3fdcc6469b89).

Comment: What if we assume there is a third competitor, Carol, and Bob pays careful attention to ruin only Alice and not Carol, so that he never enjoys a monopoly? Say he sets up shop right next to Alice and undercuts her prices slightly so that from a customers perspective it's always worth to go to Bob instead of Alice, but if you are closer to Carols shop, the difference isn't large enough to motivate you to go the slightly farther distance to Bob?

Comment: Or what if Bob sets up two companies D and E which genuinely compete with each other, but both cut prices unreasonably low below Alice? He might even convince his friend Fred to buy majority shares of one of the companies so he doesn't own both.

Comment: Do you know if Bob is allowed to compete with Alice in a way other than the consumer price, e.g. if he offers Alice's employees better salaries to get them all to leave?

Comment: I think Walmart just struggled with the German market per se. They bought a not very large chain, and first thing the annoyed all the old management to the point of quitting. They never managed to become competitive. Their usually MO of trying to control their suppliers failed spectacularly (Supplier gets a call: "We are coming tomorrow to inspect your factory". German supplier replies "You're not.". ) Customers never saw a reason to enter their stores.

Comment: @Allure An employer is allowed to offer better salaries than competitors.

Comment: Predatory pricing is indeed illegal under EU law. https://www.concurrences.com/en/glossary/predatory-pricing

Comment: The European Union is abbreviated EU, not E.U.

Comment: @gnasher729 Customers not only saw no reason to enter their stores, they drove customers away by having overbearing staff. That culture works in the US, but it annoyed the heck out of people here.

Comment: If putting Alice out of business creates a monopoly for Bob, that implies that Alice had a monopoly to begin with.

Comment: @Allure Bob is generally allowed to compete with Alice in normal, economically rational ways that aren't intended to create a monopoly or cartel. I don't know of any jurisdictions where recruiting away employees is generally prohibited.

Comment: @gnasher729: Why did the suppliers have such a big issue with Walmart inspecting their factories?  Making sure your supplier is doing things right seems like it would simply be common business sense.

Comment: In France you have fixed dates for sales ("sales" as in "time where you advertise -40% on your products so that people rush to buy them") because it is forbidden to sale at loss outside of this window. This is getting more an more complicated with global purchases, but the point is that your "predatory pricing" is indeed illegal.

Comment: @Sean Well, for one thing, they would probably want more than a day's notice.  Walmart were not a regulatory body, they were a customer. They do not get to declare short-notice inspections. They are allowed to *request* to tour/inspect the factory, within reasonable circumstances (such as date/time, security accompaniment, certain areas being off-limits for confidential or safety purposes, et cetera) to be defined by the supplier. Basically: saying "we would like to inspect your factory" is fine, but just saying "we will inspect the factory tomorrow" is an arrogant power play, and backfired.

Comment: In Germany it's only considered predatory pricing ("dumping price"), it if't under the cost of aquisition and/or manufacturing. So you can legally go as low as you wish with your winnings, but can never go negative. Note that it is also forbidden under the WTOs General Agreement on Tariffs and Trade, Article VI.

Comment: @Sean Why would the suppliers allow this inspection if they do not do it for their other customers? In the USA, Walmart might be the supplier's biggest customer (so the supplier has to comply or lose a large amount of business). In Germany, they would be one small customer out of a thousand, and thinking they have the same privileges as they get from being the biggest customer is just stupid.

Comment: @Barmar I don't think that's true. It may just be that Bob takes out several other competitors incidental to his campaign against Alice.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/110612/discussion-on-answer-by-bdb484-can-a-person-start-new-businesses-to-compete-rele).

Answer (score 19):

City planing (Stadtplanung) may regulate the distance between businesses with similar offers that you have to follow to get a permit.

Number 4 from [this official German website](http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/uwg_2004/__4.html) seems pretty broadly applicable.
"Unfairly acts (the person) who... hinders competitors in a targeted way". Though you would have to ask a lawyer if this was actually applicable. Laws are not always formulated how we would commonly interpret language.

Comment: That's interesting about "city planning".  In the two places I've lived (Canada and the US), it's not unusual for related businesses to be very close to each other (say finding 4 camera shops on the same block, or a MacDonalds and Burger King (or two competing pharmacies) across the street from each other.

Comment: @Flydog57 this is highly depended on the city and local regulations. It is very common here too to have similar shops next to each other (e.g. McD & BK close to each other,car dealer miles, clothing districts, etc.).  In general zoning laws are much more broad (e.g. where industry is allowed and where not, where bars can be, etc. )than focusing on individual businesses. Smaller communities are more involved in terms of defining "target shops" for communal spaces they own but overall Germany does not prescribe business where they can and cannot be to a larger degree than the US.

Comment: @Fnguyen It does not do it to a larger degree? So it does it to a smaller degree?

Comment: @user253751 I mean "To roughly the same degree", that is worded strange I see now.

Comment: [§4a UWG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_uwg/englisch_uwg.html#p0045) is even more to the point since it says that "significantly impairing the [...] other market participant’s freedom of choice by 1. harrassment" is an unfair aggressive practice.

Answer (score 4):

If this is not just hypothetical, Alice might need a German lawyer and not just some folks on an English-language internet forum.

- It is common that commercial rental contracts contain a non-competition clause for other, nearby properties *held by the same landlord.* So the situation in a commercial shopping mall would differ from the situation on opposite sides of the street.
- Rules against "improper competition" cover a many [different cases](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unlauterer_Wettbewerb), but not usually offering the same service cheaper. Selling food [below purchase price](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Einstandspreis#Verbot_des_Verkaufs_unter_Einstandspreis) over a long period is a special case.
- If a business is not operated with [the intention to make a profit](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gewinnerzielungsabsicht), then the tax office might not consider it a business. But that doesn't mean a startup can't make losses at first. So Bob should talk to his tax advisor.
- In some cities, zoning laws limit e.g. the density of [gaming parlors](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spielautomat#Gewerblich_betriebene_Spielautomaten_in_Deutschland). They would not usually limit the density of restaurants if other commercial activity would be allowed in that zone.

Answer (score 3):

Provided Bob's business practices are not anti-competitive and there is no direct personal confrontation or attempts to impede Alice's business by interference in her property, it is unlikely that this kind of practice is illegal.

Many competing business owners do in fact hate each other and take legal steps to grow their own business at the expense of the others and make their business more competitive than the others.

Comment: Why would the jurisdiction's competition laws not be a barrier?

Comment: @bdb484 competition laws generally kick into action when a participant has (or is about to have) a dominant market position. The original question seems to imply small, privately owned and managed businesses in fragmented markets where neither Alice nor Bob could be even close to a dominant position in the market. Tactics like predatory pricing are prohibited *if* (for example) Alice's exit from the market could lead to a monopoly for Bob, and *not* prohibited otherwise; large restaurant chains have competition restrictions that don't matter for individual restaurants with tiny market share.

Comment: I believe that would be correct in the United States, but my (admittedly limited) understanding of Germany's Act Against Restraints of Competition, predatory pricing is prohibited without respect to the resulting changes in market share.

Comment: @bdb it certainly does not seem so - e.g. the section 20.3 of that law (http://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/englisch_gwb/englisch_gwb.html#p0066) prohibits sale of food or goods under cost with the following limit "Undertakings with superior market power in relation to small and medium-sized competitors may not abuse their market position to impede such competitors directly or indirectly in an unfair manner" - the clause applies only in case of superior relative market power, it would apply to a major chain pushing out Alice, but would not apply to Bob opening a restaurant next to Alice.

Comment: I guess the part that has me wondering (and we may just be dealing with translation issues here) is the difference between market *position* and market *power*. Bob doesn't sound like he has a stronger market position, but I've been thinking of him as having more market power because he has the resources to undercut her long enough to drive her out of business.

Comment: @bdb484 That is not what market power means. Market power is the ability to unilaterally affect the terms of the market, that is, being a price giver rather than a price taker. It's essentially a measure of the extent of a monopoly.

Comment: @KevinArlin That sounds right, but why doesn't that describe Bob? He has the resources to enter any business in any market and undercut Alice until he drives her out of business? His resources don't come from existing market share, but don't they nonetheless make him a price maker capable of effecting anticompetitive outcomes?

Comment: @Peteris As I understand the situation in Germany, that article puts a special emphasis on anyone with considerable market power (and there may be an argument that Bob is in such a position if he sets up his business with sufficient funds for such a strategy). Selling under cost in itself is legal, but *harrassing*  another business is not - and that's regardless of size. There are perfectly fair reasons why it may be an economically sensible and fair business practice to sell under cost, e.g. to cut losses, clearing sale, etc. and that would be legal.

Answer (score 2):

I found a Dutch study (https://zoek.officielebekendmakingen.nl/kst-29800-XIII-86-b2.pdf), containing an international (Europe-centric) comparison of laws permitting or forbidding the sale of goods at a loss.

In short, Germany, one of the countries in the study, has a specific law on economic competition: "Gesetz gegen Wettbewerbsbeschränkungen" (1st of januari 1999).

Glossing over the brief explanation of the law in the study, I strongly suspect this behaviour would violate (at least) this law.

Answer (score -4):

Either the jurisdiction does matter, or all jurisdictions have the same laws. Which do you think is true?

Of course you can start a business to compete with people you hate, but not legally. Here in the UK, companies may do only what their articles of association specify and the powers that be would not accept "to compete with people they hate" as legitimate aims… so what? That's a technicality.

On the other hand, what you describe clearly represents harassment which here in the UK is a crime in and of itself, nothing to do with "business" as such.

Could you try running the idea that harassment must be  humiliating or embarrassing past two or three lawyers… or even one?

Comment: What are articles of association? They appear to be constitutions for companies. Of course Bob won't write "to compete with people I hate", he'll write "to sell food at low cost" or something like that.

Comment: Did you notice "so what? That's a technicality"

Go back to the Question and ask yourself what would be the point, unless this was - somehow, wierdly - about the legalities.

Otherwise, why would anyone Answer anything but "Of course… Why not?"